# How can I use getimagesize() with $_FILES['']?

Tags: php, file, upload

I am doing an image upload handler and I would like it to detect the dimensions of the image that's been uploaded by the user.

So I start with:

```
if (isset($_FILES['image'])) etc....
```

and I have

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize(...);
```

How am i supposed to use them together?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can do this as such

```
$filename = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$size = getimagesize($filename);

// or

list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
// USAGE:  echo $width; echo $height;
```

Using the condition combined, here is an example

```
if (isset($_FILES['image'])) {
    $filename = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
    echo $width; 
    echo $height;    
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Is that $size an array of all the attributes of the image? I am just looking for just the height and width, so I guess these are elements of that array? Thanks

Comment: @eric01, No, you can use it with list to. I have updated with an example

Comment: @Starx What if i have multiple files? :x

Answer (score 2):

Try this for multi images :

```
for($i=0; $i < count($filenames); $i++){  

    $image_info = getimagesize($images['tmp_name'][$i]);
    $image_width  = $image_info[0];
    $image_height = $image_info[1];
}
```

Try this for single image :

```
$image_info = getimagesize($images['tmp_name']);
$image_width  = $image_info[0];
$image_height = $image_info[1];
```

at least it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

from php manual very simple example.

```
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize("img/flag.jpg");
echo "<img src=\"img/flag.jpg\" $attr alt=\"getimagesize() example\" />";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list($w, $h) = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
```

From the docs:

> **Index 0 and 1 contains respectively the width and the height of the image.**
>
> Index 2 is one of the IMAGETYPE_XXX constants indicating the type of
>   the image.
>
> Index 3 is a text string with the correct height="yyy" width="xxx"
>   string that can be used directly in an IMG tag.

So you can just do list() and don't worry about indexes, it should get the info you need :)