# Uploading a file with twig and Slim framework (Version 2) - PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, twig, slim, userfrosting

I'm using UserFrosting a user management system and I'm having some trouble uploading a file through form post, this is what I tried

**This is how my twig file looks.**

```
<form name="eveniment" method="post" action="{{form_action}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  ...
  <input type="file" class="form-control" name="poza" id="poza">
  ...
</form>`
```

**This is how my controller looks like**

```
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["poza"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
$check = getimagesize($_FILES);
if($check !== false) {
    $ms->addMessage("success", "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".");
    $uploadOk = 1;
} else {
    $ms->addMessage("danger", "File is not an image.");
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
$ms->addMessage("success", $target_file);
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    $ms->addMessage("danger", "Sorry, file already exists.");
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["poza"]["size"] > 500000) {
    $ms->addMessage("danger", "Sorry, your file is too large.");
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    $ms->addMessage("danger", "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.");
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["poza"]["name"], $target_file)) {
        $ms->addMessage("success", "The file ". basename( $_FILES["poza"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.");
    } else {
        $ms->addMessage("danger",  "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.");
    }
}
```

**Route**

```
$app->post('/evenimente/?', function () use ($app) {
    $controller = new UF\EvenimentController($app);
    return $controller->createEveniment();
});
```

**PHP configuration**

`file_uploads On`

`upload_max_filesize    128M`

Every other input is posted succesfully, except this one with the type="file".

I don't have any errors, I tried different ways, but with no success. Also if I print `$_FILES["poza"]["name"]` it will be empty.

Comment: Are you sure that you're sending the request to your controller?

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code, not from this angle. Start troubleshooting one component at a time. Begin by posting to your route with a file upload.

Comment: @DavidePastore Yes, I am, the other fields are posted successfully. Here is my route :     $app->post('/evenimente/?', function () use ($app) {
        $controller = new UF\EvenimentController($app);
        return $controller->createEveniment();
    });

Comment: `var_dump($_FILES);`

Comment: `getimagesize($_FILES)` – that‘s nonsense of course, you can not call that function by passing the complete $_FILES array into it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9799343/how-can-i-use-getimagesize-with-files

Comment: @CBroe $_FILES is empty

Comment: How big is the file you are uploading? If the file size is larger than your web server allows it will behave exactly as you are describing

Comment: @geggleto the maximum file size is set to 128 mb. My files is 2mb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is assuming you're using UserFrosting, since you linked this question in the UserFrosting Gitter chat.

UserFrosting includes CSRFGuard Middleware to make sure all POST requests originated locally. You need to include the CSRF token to ensure that the middleware does not block the POST request.

Since the token is already in the Twig global variables, the easiest way is to use a hidden form field with the CSRF token in it:

```
<input type="hidden" name="{{csrf_key}}" value="{{csrf_token}}">
```